# c++ textbox doesn't let you type

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a simple chat program where clients can send messages to a server, which shows the received messages. For some reason, I can't type in the textbox even though its not set to read only. Can anyone see the simple error without me posting the entire code? This is where i create the textbox:

```
static HWND text;

switch(msg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        text = CreateWindow(TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("Enter text here..."),
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                     0, 0, 300, 25,
                     hwnd, (HMENU) ID_EDIT, NULL, NULL);

        CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Post"),
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                     310, 0, 70, 25,
                     hwnd, (HMENU) ID_POST, NULL, NULL);

        CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Connect"),
                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                     0, 35, 70, 25,
                     hwnd, (HMENU) ID_CONNECT, NULL, NULL);

        break;
    }
```

Comment: Is it enabled and focusable? Do you even see the caret blink?

Comment: @K-ballo, you can select it (caret flashes), but you can't type in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Applying my mental powers, I'd say that you wrote your own message loop in the main function and that you are not calling `TranslateMessage()`.

Function [`TranslateMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is responsible for converting key messages into char messages (no, that's not done automatically :-). The end result is that your EDIT windows (all your windows) do not receive `WM_CHAR` messages.

So your message loop should at least have something like this:

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: @rodrigo, extremely helpful, I knew it was something trivial! The line somehow got skipped.

Comment: @K-ballo - The funny thing is that whenever I wrote plain Win32 programs, I always wondered what would happen if I forgot to call `TranslateMessage()`, but I never actually tried it. I simply imagined  something like that.